# Blank Half white screen during page navigation in ionic on android device

Tags: ionic-framework

I am stuck with one weird issue which only occurred in device during transition in state in Ionic App,it show blank white half screen on bottom. 
I have tried various suggestions http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/brief-black-screen-d…/…/48 but nothing worked out even i had forcefully set the body height and background-color using jquery.Still,issue remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Below is Screen shot of Login screen view so you guys can found what really issue is.

Comment: Hi, Have you resolved this issue.